# Gas valve with on off indicator?

Tags: gas, valve

Is there such a thing as a gas valve with an on/off indicator light?

I'm looking for something where it's **blindingly obvious** that somebody has left the gas on.

ironically: I googled around but couldn't see anything obvious jump out.

---

More detail:

I'm looking to build an outdoor BBQ, I want a gas valve by the kitchen door to shut the gas off outside.

Comment: You mean the gas on the stove?  Could you describe more about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hey Jeff, Sorry for the lack of clarity - I've added more detail.
It's for an outdoor BBQ I'm building, I want a gas off valve inside and to be sure that I never leave the gas on outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something that shuts [off the gas automatically after a configurable amount of time](http://www.buygasgrills.com/Automatic-Shut-Off-Valve-by-Fire-Magic-p/3090.htm)?

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty good idea! I like it lots, surprised that it's $97 though! was kind of expecting it to be a tenth of that price...

For safety this seems like the best answer however.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just use a [ball valve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_valve)?  These valves make it easy to tell if they are open or closed.

In the open position (gas is flowing) the handle (lever) will be parallel with the pipe, when it is closed (gas not flowing) the handle (lever) will be perpendicular to the pipe.

This should make it easy for you to tell if the gas is on, or off.

[image]

Comment: you can also easily add a visual indicator to a ball valve. cut out 2 circles the same size from a piece of plastic, about a 3 inch radius, or as big as you want your indicator. on one of the pieces of plastic, cut out a quarter "pizza slice". on the other one, write ON and OFF in 2 different but adjacent quadrants. ON must be to the right. remove the handle from the valve and attach the ON/OFF one to the valve, then attach the 3/4's circle to the handle. reinstall handle. turning the handle moves the cutout and exposes either ON or OFF.

Comment: This is the best feature of ball valves. They are extremely intuitive. If is 90 degrees to the pipe it looks like it's "blocking" the flow, and it is.

Comment: Not really obvious enough, intuitive yes... but it doesn't shout out "you left me on!"...